# Xcode 4 templates don't work in iOS 3.1.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash

I would like to test my app for older phones, and got one with 3.1.2. But when I try to run it, it just show the splash screen and then crash.

Then I tried to make a new Hello World view-based app from Xcode 4 templates, but even with this one it build fine but crash on startup. I set deployment target to 3.1.

If i try to run this one with iPad 3.2 simulator, it also crashes.

Where can the problem be?

When i run it on iOS device, it gives this warnings and then just stop, not really crash:

warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1/Symbols/System/Library/Priv

UPDATE:
I found that I earlier had made a shortcut from 3.1.2 (7D11) to 3.1.2 in the DeviceSupport folder for some reason. I removed that and now I don't get the warnings anymore. Just a crash ;)

> 0   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x000000010010974a internal_vproblem +
>   308 1   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x0000000100109924 internal_verror +
>   27 2   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x00000001001099c2 align_down + 0 3
>   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x0000000100150c5e macosx_solib_add +
>   794 4   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x000000010016417c
>   remote_macosx_complete_create_or_attach
>   + 187 5   gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x000000010016489e
>   remote_macosx_create_inferior + 1252 6
>   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x000000010005f6c3 run_command_1 + 586
>   7   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x0000000100107b7f execute_command +
>   557 8   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x00000001000171e7
>   mi_execute_async_cli_command + 204 9
>   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x00000001000168e5
>   captured_mi_execute_command + 344 10 
>   gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x0000000100072a62 catch_exception +
>   57 11  gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x000000010001443e mi_execute_command
>   + 140 12  gdb-arm-apple-darwin                0x0000000100077721 process_event + 133
>   13  gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x0000000100078435 gdb_do_one_event +
>   1049 14  gdb-arm-apple-darwin
>   0x0000000100072b49 catch_errors + 70
>   /SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1518/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-dyld.c:1648:
>   internal-error: unrecognized shared
>   library breakpoint A problem internal
>   to GDB has been detected, further
>   debugging may prove unreliable.

When i run iPad simulator, it crash on this line in HelloWorldAppDelegate.m:
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

with this message:
2011-04-21 11:46:09.006 HelloWorld[5492:207] *** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c11bb0
2011-04-21 11:46:09.007 HelloWorld[5492:207]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c11bb0'

UPDATE:
This was solved by this:

```
//  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window addSubview: [self.viewController view]];
```

Comment: Try with NSLog() to figure out at which point the application stops.

Comment: I downloaded a new (4.0.2) version of Xcode and now it works. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[window addSubview: [myRootViewController view]];` instead of `[window: setRootViewController: myRootViewController];` in your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it work in the iPad 3.2 simulator, but still the old iPhone just stops (without error).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem as you, and every app I created from an Xcode 4 template would give me the error you describe. By looking at some of the sample code included with Xcode 4's online documentation, I discovered that it works on an iPhone 3G running 3.1.3 if I replaced

`self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;`

with

`[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];`

That did it for iPhone running 3.1.3.